# Which technique does scipy.integrate.quad use

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

The [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) states that `integrate.quad` uses "a technique from the Fortran library QUADPACK". [QUADPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUADPACK) provides several routines using different techniques. Which one(s) does `integrate.quad` use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to your question is given in a previous post:

[How to know integration technique used by quadpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153436/how-to-know-integration-technique-used-by-quadpack)

> For finite integration limits, the integration is performed using a
>   Clenshaw-Curtis method which uses Chebyshev moments. ... If one of the
>   integration limits is infinite, then a Fourier integral is computed
>   (assuming w neq 0).